# Reduce rows in results of joined query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregate-functions, resultset

Is it possible to reduce the number of rows returned from a joined query by having results from individual tables returned in some array-like container

E.g. for a query:

```
SELECT a.col, b.col, c.col FROM
   a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
     INNER JOIN c ON a.id = c.id
```

where it is known a.id uniquely matches 1 row in a, b.id matches 2 rows in b and c.id matches 3 rows in c, the results would then be

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| a.col | b.col | c.col |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   A0  |   B1  |   C1  |
|   A0  |   B2  |   C1  |
|   A0  |   B1  |   C2  |
|   A0  |   B2  |   C2  |
|   A0  |   B1  |   C3  |
|   A0  |   B2  |   C3  | 
+-------+-------+-------+
6 rows in set
```

So question is if it some how would be possible to reduce output to something like (or similar)

```
+-------+----------+--------------+
| A.col |  b....   |  c....       |
+-------+----------+--------------+
|   A0  | [B1, B2] | [C1, C2, C3] |
+-------+----------+--------------+
```

Perhaps instead of array-like structure form strings (array like to me...), e.g. "B1,B2", "C1,C2,C3"

Note, can't use `DISTINCT` as b.col may contain identical values.

What if one wishes more than one column from table b, e.g.

````
SELECT a.col, b.col, b.col2, c.col FROM
   a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
     INNER JOIN c ON a.id = c.id
```
how to get a result on form (or similar)
```
+-------+------------------------+--------------+
| A.col |  b....                 |  c....       |
+-------+------------------------+--------------+
|   A0  | [[B1, B11], [B2, B21]] | [C1, C2, C3] |
+-------+------------------------+--------------+
```
Would it perhaps be possible/wise to prior to `JOIN` table a and b create a temporary table btmp with the desired output (as a string or similar).

At the end of the day I wish to access a mysql data base remotely over a line that sometimes may be quite bad, so wish to reduce the amount of data sent as far as possible without loosing required information.
````

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/). It doesn;t create arrays of values, but it does create delimited string lists. MySQL doesn't of course, have array-valued columns either in tables or result sets, so you're stuck with strings.

I believe this will do something close to what you want.

```sql
SELECT a.col, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.col) b
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.col) c 
  FROM a
 INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
 INNER JOIN c ON a.id = c.id  -- you had a.id = b.id but that won't work.
 GROUP BY a.col
```

Comment: Interesting, but would not work as b.col as well as c.col may contain identical values.